# How to get ros2 param list to work with simple custom node?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have following test.cpp:

```
#include <project/test.h>

void signalHandler(int signum){
    std::cerr << "Received signal" << std::endl;
    rclcpp::shutdown();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    signal(SIGTERM, signalHandler);

    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor exe;

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> lc_node = std::make_shared<Foo>();

    exe.add_node(lc_node->get_node_base_interface());
    exe.spin();
//    rclcpp::shutdown();
    std::cerr << "Closed" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with test.h just being:

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <rclcpp_lifecycle/lifecycle_node.hpp>

class Foo : public rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode {
public:
    Foo() : rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode("foo"){
        std::cerr << "Running test node" << std::endl;
    };

private:

};
```

now I can run the node successfully directly from clion and everything works, callbacks get called topics get published and I see my published markers in rviz. Now I wanted to integrate with rqt but when I try to click on the node it just freezes and gives me following error message:

```
[WARN] [1630415189.108735450] [rqt_reconfigure]: Failed to retrieve parameters from node: asynchronous service call failed: the target node may not be spinning
```

`ros2 param list` returns `Exception while calling service of node '/foo': None`

What am I missing? Why can't I get the parameters of my node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385513/how-to-get-ros2-param-list-to-work-with-simple-custom-node?/) by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2021-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you're using a lifecycle node, You'll need to `configure` then `activate` the node before it actually does anything. You can do this with `ros2 lifecycle set /foo configure` then `ros2 lifecycle set /foo activate`. After that, the node should be running normally. You might need to implement the transition callbacks in your `Foo` class, I can't remember off the top of my head though.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2021-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0